# How to add images from a gallery to a listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview, android-gallery

I would like to add a picture from the gallery and when i press create player, I would like that picture to be added next to the players name in the listview.

Right now, my code gets pictures from drawables and these pictures are accessed within a typed array.

How do i change my code to implement it to get the picture from the gallery and display it in the listview?

Any help will be highly appreciated! Thankyou

My code for my custom adaptor is :

```
 public class PlayerImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Player> {

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

            private ArrayList<Player> players;
            private TypedArray mIcons;

            private int mViewResourceId;

            public PlayerImageAdapter(Context ctx, int viewResourceId,
                    ArrayList<Player> players, TypedArray icons) {
                super(ctx, viewResourceId, players);

                mInflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(
                        Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                this.players = players;
                mIcons = icons;

                mViewResourceId = viewResourceId;
            }


            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, null);

                ImageView iv = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.playerPic);
                iv.setImageDrawable(mIcons.getDrawable(position));

                TextView tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.playerName);
                tv.setText(this.players.get(position).toString());

                return convertView;
            }
        }


        //and my code that calls it:


    TypedArray icons = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.player_pics);

                adapter = new PlayerImageAdapter(ctx, R.layout.player_customlist,
                        dataStore.getPlayers(), icons);


        My code that access the gallery is:

         protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();

                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagePlayer);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

                }


            }
```

Comment: theres no problem in my code, it works. I just want to know how i would use the image from my gallery instead of the resources in drawable.

Comment: Just one image... and then when i press a button, that image should be viewed in a listview.

Comment: Have you looked http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-displaying-images-with-an-enhanced-gallery/ ???